Istio - 404 NR route_not_found
I have a linux box in GCP with docker installed and Prometheus running as a container.
I also have 2 GKE clusters (A & B) with istio installed (just as an ingress controller only) - service mesh is not enabled.
All 3 are in seperate projects. The linux box project is peered to project with cluster 'A' and the project with cluster 'A' is peered to project containing cluster 'B'.
Basically the GKE 'A' cluster sits in between the Linux box and the GKE 'B' cluster like a proxy.
I am trying to scrape the metrics from the Prometheus server in GKE 'B'.
Inside GKE 'A' I have the following gateway, serviceEntry and Virtual Service
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-ilb
  namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingress
  servers:
---rest ommited
    - hosts:
        - '*'
      port:
        name: http-web
        number: 9090
        protocol: HTTP

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
spec:
  endpoints:
  - address: 192.XX.XX.XX # istio loadbalancer IP of GKE B
  hosts:
  - prometheus.B.infra.internal
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: http-web
    number: 9090
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: DNS

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/target: ilb.A.infra.internal
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kube-prometheus
  name: kube-prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-ingress/istio-ilb
  hosts:
  - prometheus.A.infra.internal
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /metrics
    route:
    - destination:
        host: prometheus.B.infra.internal
        port:
          number: 9090
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: prometheus.B.infra.internal
        port:
          number: 9090

In GKE 'B; I have the following config:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-ilb
  namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingress
  servers:
---rest ommited
    - hosts:
        - '*'
      port:
        name: http-web
        number: 9090
        protocol: HTTP

piVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/target: ilb.B.infra.internal
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kube-prometheus
  name: kube-prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-ingress/istio-ilb
  hosts:
  - prometheus.B.infra.internal
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /metrics
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kube-prometheus-kube-prome-prometheus.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 9090
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kube-prometheus-kube-prome-prometheus.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 9090

The endpoint in cluster B
kube-prometheus-kube-prome-prometheus      10.31.0.89:9090,10.31.0.89:8080

I get the following errors in the istio loadbalancers of each cluster
GKE 'A'
[2024-07-25T14:32:53.435Z] "GET /metrics HTTP/1.1" 404 - via_upstream - "-" 0 0 2 2 "192.168.31.94" "Prometheus/2.52.0" "a4cfdd83-9e23-47e7-8f │
│ 35-7e0f5d6e1943" "prometheus.A.infra.internal:9090" "192.<cluster B IP>:9090" outbound|9090||prometheus.B.infra.internal 10.33.2.167:42320 10.33.2.167:9090 192.<cluster A IP>:42 │
│ 890 - -

GKE 'B'
[2024-07-25T14:38:27.043Z] "GET /metrics HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "192.<cluster A IP>,192.<cluster B IP>" "Prometheus/2.52.0" "367 │
│ 5e168-e5c8-435c-8e18-43b07162df76" "prometheus.A.infra.internal:9090" "-" - - 10.31.0.31:9090 192.168.30.83:21654 - -

A curl and nslookup from linux box to GKE 'A'
curl -I http://prometheus.A.internal:9090/metrics
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
date: Thu, 25 Jul 2024 14:41:45 GMT
server: istio-envoy
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2
transfer-encoding: chunked


nslookup prometheus.A.infra.internal
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
prometheus.A.infra.internal canonical name = ilb.A.infra.internal.
Name:   ilb.A.infra.internal
Address: 192.<cluster A IP>

From a pod in GKE 'A'
kubectl run curlpod-proxy --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty --rm

root@curlpod-proxy:/ ]$ nslookup prometheus.B.infra.internal
Server:    10.32.240.10
Address 1: 10.32.240.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      prometheus.B.infra.internal
Address 1: 192.<cluster B IP>

curl -s http://prometheus.B.infra.internal:9090/metrics | head -n 5
# HELP go_gc_cycles_automatic_gc_cycles_total Count of completed GC cycles generated by the Go runtime.
# TYPE go_gc_cycles_automatic_gc_cycles_total counter
go_gc_cycles_automatic_gc_cycles_total 16205
# HELP go_gc_cycles_forced_gc_cycles_total Count of completed GC cycles forced by the application.
# TYPE go_gc_cycles_forced_gc_cycles_total counter

istioctl pc route comd
NAME          VHOST NAME                                              DOMAINS                                            MATCH                  VIRTUAL SERVICE
http.80       prometheus.A.infra.internal:80                      prometheus.A.infra.internal                    /metrics               kube-prometheus.monitoring
http.80       prometheus.A.infra.internal:80                      prometheus.A.infra.internal                    /*                     kube-prometheus.monitoring

http.9090     prometheus.B.infra.internal:9090                prometheus.B.infra.internal                /metrics                                     kube-prometheus.monitoring
http.9090     prometheus.B.infra.internal:9090                prometheus.B.infra.internal                /*                                           kube-prometheus.monitoring

What am I doing wrong? - is it possible what I'm trying to do?

Something I read in your links got it to work. I changed the host from prometheus.B.infra.internal to'*'. This resulted in a 200 and I was able to gather metrics. Still a bit confused becuase as soon as I remove prometheus.B.infra.internal then my externalDNS would remove that DNS yet virtual service in A cluster is still pointing to it even though it doesn't exist. Would still prefer not to use a wildcard though.

Go through this Document which might be helpful for you.

When a 404 is returned by the istio-ingress gateway, it generally means there is a listener configured for the endpoint port, however there were no routes matching that particular request, so Istio used the default route which returns a 404.
It is important to distinguish a 404 returned by Istio from a 404 returned by the application itself. If the istio-ingressgateway is returning 404s you will see a 404 NR entry in its access log and no traffic will hit the actual application backend (i.e the requests won't show in the app's sidecar logs).
Try Troubleshooting the cluster using the istioctl analyze.
Also check this Ingress gateway troubleshooting which might be helpful.
Refer through this Stack Link which will help you to resolve your issue.
